# How can I find the average number of entries for a column in a set of long data

Tags: r

I am new to R and I surprisingly couldn't find an answer to this using the search function. Assuming I have a set of data as follows:

```
 Plot Rate Rep Plant Tuber Weight
1    101    1   1     1     1  179.4
2    101    1   1     1     2   99.4
3    101    1   1     1     3   72.4
4    101    1   1     1     4  111.5
5    101    1   1     1     5   44.9
6    101    1   1     1     6   55.3
7    101    1   1     1     7   12.6
8    101    1   1     1     8  106.7
9    101    1   1     1     9   96.7
10   101    1   1     1    10   52.5
11   101    1   1     2     1  151.1
12   101    1   1     2     2  171.7
13   101    1   1     2     3   93.0
14   101    1   1     2     4   82.4
15   101    1   1     2     5  143.9
16   101    1   1     2     6  115.6
17   101    1   1     2     7  141.3
18   101    1   1     2     8   72.6
19   101    1   1     2     9   97.2
20   101    1   1     2    10  146.8
21   101    1   1     2    11  104.0
22   101    1   1     2    12  121.6
23   101    1   1     3     1  150.9
24   101    1   1     3     2   47.1
25   101    1   1     3     3   59.6
26   101    1   1     3     4   94.2
27   101    1   1     3     5  167.4
28   101    1   1     3     6   55.2
29   101    1   1     3     7   21.8
30   101    1   1     3     8   79.6
31   101    1   1     3     9   92.2
32   101    1   1     3    10   78.0
33   101    1   1     3    11   61.8
34   101    1   1     3    12    9.5
35   101    1   1     3    13    2.7
36   101    1   1     3    14    3.8
37   101    1   1     3    15    1.1
38   106    1   2     1     1   50.7
39   106    1   2     1     2  148.8
40   106    1   2     1     3   50.6
41   106    1   2     1     4  129.6
42   106    1   2     1     5   69.7
43   106    1   2     1     6   83.4
44   106    1   2     1     7   49.1
45   106    1   2     1     8  100.4
46   106    1   2     1     9   33.0
47   106    1   2     1    10    0.8
```

Here, there is a weight entry for each tuber collected from treatment combinations of Rate, Rep, and Plant.

How can I find the overall average number of tubers found in the Rate/Rep/Plant combos? For example, there are 10 tubers in 1/1/1 and 12 tubers in 1/1/2. I am looking for the average number of tubers found in a plant. The way that the tubers are expressed one at a time in a column makes this difficult for me. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(Plot, Rate, Rep, Plant) %>% summarise(n = mean(Tuber))` or `df1 %>% group_by(Rate, Rep, Plant) %>% summarise(n = mean(Tuber))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add a little to what @akrun said here. You can use `dplyr::group_by`, and then find the number of tubers in a plant by taking the maximum value of `Tubers` within each Rate/Rep/Plant group. Then finding the average number of tubers per plant is easy:

```
df <- data.table::fread(
"Row Plot Rate Rep Plant Tuber Weight
1    101    1   1     1     1  179.4
2    101    1   1     1     2   99.4
3    101    1   1     1     3   72.4
4    101    1   1     1     4  111.5
5    101    1   1     1     5   44.9
6    101    1   1     1     6   55.3
7    101    1   1     1     7   12.6
8    101    1   1     1     8  106.7
9    101    1   1     1     9   96.7
10   101    1   1     1    10   52.5
11   101    1   1     2     1  151.1
12   101    1   1     2     2  171.7
13   101    1   1     2     3   93.0
14   101    1   1     2     4   82.4
15   101    1   1     2     5  143.9
16   101    1   1     2     6  115.6
17   101    1   1     2     7  141.3
18   101    1   1     2     8   72.6
19   101    1   1     2     9   97.2
20   101    1   1     2    10  146.8
21   101    1   1     2    11  104.0
22   101    1   1     2    12  121.6
23   101    1   1     3     1  150.9
24   101    1   1     3     2   47.1
25   101    1   1     3     3   59.6
26   101    1   1     3     4   94.2
27   101    1   1     3     5  167.4
28   101    1   1     3     6   55.2
29   101    1   1     3     7   21.8
30   101    1   1     3     8   79.6
31   101    1   1     3     9   92.2
32   101    1   1     3    10   78.0
33   101    1   1     3    11   61.8
34   101    1   1     3    12    9.5
35   101    1   1     3    13    2.7
36   101    1   1     3    14    3.8
37   101    1   1     3    15    1.1
38   106    1   2     1     1   50.7
39   106    1   2     1     2  148.8
40   106    1   2     1     3   50.6
41   106    1   2     1     4  129.6
42   106    1   2     1     5   69.7
43   106    1   2     1     6   83.4
44   106    1   2     1     7   49.1
45   106    1   2     1     8  100.4
46   106    1   2     1     9   33.0
47   106    1   2     1    10    0.8"
)

library(tidyverse)
tubers_per_plant <- df %>% 
  group_by(Rate,Rep,Plant) %>% 
  summarize(num_Tubers = max(Tuber))
tubers_per_plant
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   Rate, Rep [2]
   Rate   Rep Plant num_Tubers
  <int> <int> <int>      <int>
1     1     1     1         10
2     1     1     2         12
3     1     1     3         15
4     1     2     1         10

mean(tubers_per_plant$num_Tubers)
[1] 11.75
```